# Where GNOME Sound Recorder save sound clips?

Tags: sound, ubuntu-mate, sound-recorder

I used [GNOME Sound Recorder](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/SoundRecorder) to record some sounds (as mp3), but now I cant find the files. I read that the files would be saved in my home directory (google). but they aren't there. The clips show up in the sound recorder app. 
So then I did `locate *.mp3` which shows a bunch of my music files, but not the sounds I just recorded. so then I did `sudo updatedb` and tried the locate command again. no change.

Where are the sound files kept?

OS: Ubuntu Mate 18.10

Comment: Not familiar with sound recorder on Mate but what you can do is launch recorder with strace, as in strace -e open,openat soundrecordercommandhere , and see what file comes up in the output

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Prior to version 3.28.1, the application `gnome-sound-recorder` (version 3.28.1) saves files in the `~/Recordings/` folder, ie it creates a folder called Recordings in the users home directory. A search for ".mp3" won't find the files as they are saved as ".ogg" (OggVorbis).

This can be confirmed, as [Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy](https://askubuntu.com/users/295286/sergiy-kolodyazhnyy) indicates, by using strace, eg:

```
strace -e trace=%file,openat -o "| grep AT_FDCWD" gnome-sound-recorder
```

which gives output like:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/USER/Recordings/Clip 1", O_RDONLY) = 20
```

Edit:

As of 2022-02-05, on Kubuntu 21.04 using gnome-sound-recorder "40.beta" (40~beta-1) the file is named `Recording 1` and placed in `/home/$USER/.local/share/org.gnome.SoundRecorder/`. @PaulM reports it being placed in `~/.var/app/org.gnome.SoundRecorder/data/org.gnome.SoundRecorder` (v.40.0).

Other

Comment: [Maybe soon you'll find it under Documents or Music](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-sound-recorder/issues/20)

Comment: I will check this out, I used to use gnome sound recorder(years ago), and never had  such problems.

Comment: This is now (v 40.0) ~/.var/app/org.gnome.SoundRecorder/data/org.gnome.SoundRecorder

Comment: Confirmed that new location is `/home/$USER/.local/share/org.gnome.SoundRecorder/` also in Ubuntu Gnome 22.04 and PoP! OS. (no surprise). Thanks! I also added context to the beginning of the answer so the google snippet wouldn't be misleading. And it seems the current format default is FLAC, with no file format extension like `.mp3`.